# Why do we use "&cell_reference&" in Excel?

Tags: excel-formula

Lets say we have a table like this:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Aaron | 20 |
| 2 | Bob | 30 |

What is the difference between `=""&A1&" has "&B1&" cakes"` and `= A1 & " has " & B1 & " cakes"`?

Why do we use "&cell_reference&" anyways?

Comment: The question might get closed as being an opinion. I can't think of any reason to use `=""&` at the start.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook What does "&A1&" means anyway?

Comment: It means take the value in `A1` and stick it (concatenate) with whatever is in the text string. The first `=""` is just an empty string so no point putting it in.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Why doesn't then ="A1" equals ="&A1" or ="A1&"?

Comment: The first `"` in a formula indicates start of a text string. The next `"` indicates the end. Putting `&` after that can stack multiple strings by opening a text string using `"` to open again, or by using cell reference (without `"`'s) `A1` after it or in between two text strings. This means the value of cell `A1` is added in between the strings after or in between the `"`'s.

Comment: @P.b So, basically "&A1&" would mean something like ""+Aaron+""?

Comment: `=A1` what hoe show `Aaron` and if the value in `A1` what hoe change the shown value in that linked cell would update to the new value as well. `="I'm "&A1&"."` would show `I'm Aaron.` updating the value in `A1` to `Fred` would make it show `I'm Fred.`.